# TypeError: fetch failed when hosting on AWS EC2 (Node.JS Application, @solana/web3.js)

Tags: web3.js

Basically most of RPC requests (approximately 80% but not all of them) are failed because of `TypeError: fetch failed`. This issue however is only observed while our app is deployed on AWS EC2.

Example code that we use:

```
const baseUrl = configService.get<string>('HELIUS_RPC_URL') as string;
const apiKey = configService.get<string>('HELIUS_API_KEY') as string;
const rpcUrl = `${baseUrl}?api-key=${apiKey}`;
this.umi = createUmi(rpcUrl);

this.rpcConnection = new Connection(rpcUrl);

const response = await this.rpcConnection.getSignaturesForAddress(walletAddress, {
                    limit: 1000, // Adjust the limit as needed
                    before: lastSignature ? lastSignature : undefined,
                }); // Error is thrown on AWS
```

Comment: having the same issue here